# Adding values from two arrays into a PSCustomObject

Tags: arrays, powershell, pscustomobject

I am trying to combine values from two arrays into a table using a PSCustomObject.

One array has the passwords and one array has the users.

When I try to combine them in to a PSCustomObject array it only list the last value in the array, not a list.

I have tried a few different versions:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $users.Length; $i++) {$myObject = [PSCustomObject] @{name = $users.name[$i]; User = $users.samaccountname[$i]; Mail = $users.mail[$i]; Password = $passwords[$i]}}
```

and

```
foreach ($psw in $passwords) {$users | % {$myObject = [PSCustomObject] @{name = $PSItem.name; User = $PSItem.samaccountname; Mail = $PSItem.mail; Password = $psw}}}
```

When I try to use `+=` on `$myobject` it gives the error:

> Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `+=`, simply assign all the output from the loop to a variable (also note that you'll probably want to index into `$users` rather than the synthetic collection(s) you get from `$users.name` etc. - otherwise it'll break if any property contains multiple values):

```
$myObjects =
  for ($i = 0; $i -lt $users.Length; $i++) {
    [PSCustomObject] @{
      Name = $users[$i].name
      User = $users[$i].samaccountname 
      Mail = $users[$i].mail
      Password = $passwords[$i]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you get when using `+=` on `$myobject` is caused because `$myobject` is of a custom type (without the 'op_Addition' method implemented).

You can use an object with this method implemented, for example ArrayList, like that:

```
$myObject = New-Object -TypeName "System.Collections.ArrayList"

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $users.Length; $i++) {
    $myObject += [PSCustomObject] @{
        Name = $users[$i].name
        User = $users[$i].samaccountname 
        Mail = $users[$i].mail
        Password = $passwords[$i]
    }    
}
```

Comment: You don't add elements to an `ArrayList` using `+=`.